# TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

Can't change `useState` variable in `useEffect` hook. Needs to change `displayedVal` after changing `inputVal`. Making search component.

my code

```
function SmallSelect(props: smallSelectProps) {


const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('')
const [displayedVal, setDisplayedVal] = useState<option[]>(props.data.slice(0, 24))
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
const [namesRepeats, setNamesRepeats] = useState(false)
const [displayVal, setDisplayVal] = useState<React.Component<any>>()

const handleChangeInput = (value: string) => {

    setInputVal(value.replace(/[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я,-]/g, ''))

    let outArr: option[] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < props.data.length; i++) {
        if (props.data[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(inputVal.toLowerCase())) {
            outArr.push(props.data[i])
        }
    }

    namesRepeats ? setDisplayedVal(outArr.slice(0, 12).sort()) : setDisplayedVal(outArr.slice(0, 24).sort())
}

const handleOptionClick = (val: option) => {
    setActive(false)
    setInputVal(val.name)
    setSelected(true)
    props.onChangeFunc(val.population)
}
useEffect(() => {
    const displayVal = useMemo<React.ReactElement[] | null>(() => {
        if (displayedVal.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return displayedVal.map((city: option) => (
            <Option key={city.population as number} onClickFoo={handleOptionClick} option={city} repeats={namesRepeats} />
        ));
    }, [displayedVal, namesRepeats]);
```

Tryed many types and many times asked perplexity for help. It said ony about wrong type. Understanding about infinite loop in useEffect, but anyway can't make something.